# "this" in a prototype method does not always refer to the prototype of the object itself?

Tags: coffeescript, prototype, this

Most of the times all I have to do with JavaScript is just add some dynamics to simple HTML. Recently, however, after discovering CoffeeScript, I got interested in *Object Oriented JavaScript". Here is some code in CoffeeScript.

```
class MyClass
    constructor: (title, purpose)->
        @title = typeof title is undefined ? "My Class" : title
        @purpose = typeof purpose is undefined ? "None" : purpose
        @myMethod()

    myMethod: ->
        _getTitle = @getTitle
        _getPurpose = @getPurpose
        $(window).click ->
            _getTitle()
            _getPurpose()
            return
        return

    getTitle: ->
        _title = @title
        window.console.log "Title of the class this object belongs to is: #{_title}"
        return

    getPurpose: ->
        _purpose = @purpose
        window.console.log "Purpose of creating this class is: #{_purpose}"
        return

    title = ""
    purpose = ""

myObject = new MyClass("Testbed", "to test Object Oriented JavaScript")
```

For those who prefer JavaScript, here is the compiled (?) JavaScript.

```
var MyClass, myObject;

MyClass = (function() {
  var purpose, title;

  function MyClass(title, purpose) {
    var _ref, _ref1;
    this.title = (_ref = typeof title === void 0) != null ? _ref : {
      "My Class": title
    };
    this.purpose = (_ref1 = typeof purpose === void 0) != null ? _ref1 : {
      "None": purpose
    };
    this.myMethod();
  }

  MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    var _getPurpose, _getTitle;
    _getTitle = this.getTitle;
    _getPurpose = this.getPurpose;
    $(window).click(function() {
      _getTitle();
      _getPurpose();
    });
  };

  MyClass.prototype.getTitle = function() {
    var _title;
    _title = this.title;
    window.console.log("Title of the class this object belongs to is: " + _title);
  };

  MyClass.prototype.getPurpose = function() {
    var _purpose;
    _purpose = this.purpose;
    window.console.log("Purpose of creating this class is: " + _purpose);
  };

  title = "";

  purpose = "";

  return MyClass;

})();

myObject = new MyClass("Testbed", "to test Object Oriented JavaScript");
```

Sorry about the long code. I had to try to keep it interesting. The thing is, this code outputs:

```
Title of the class this object belongs to is: undefined
Purpose of creating this class is: undefined
```

whereas I was expecting it to output:

```
Title of the class this object belongs to is: Testbed
Purpose of creating this class is: to test Object Oriented JavaScript
```

And I could've sworn this was how it worked when I last tinkered with it (around six months ago). I learnt that in a method that is part of the *prototype* of an object, `this` refers to the prototype itself. And `this.something` would actually point to `object.something`. Whereas in this example, inside `myObject.myMethod()`, `this` behaves as it should and `this.getTitle()` refers to `myObject.getTitle()`. Inside `myObject.getTitle()`, however, `this` refers to `window`. Why?

Is it because `getTitle()` was called inside a `$(window).click()` handler? But why would that change the context? `getTitle()` is still a property of `myObject`.

Also, you see what I am trying to accomplish here. How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems.

1) You never return anything from `.getPurpose` or `.getTitle`

2) You should create a reference to this in myMethod. i.e. `var me = this` and then inside the event listener call `me.getTitle()` and `me.getPurpose()`. This is needed because inside the event listener (window onclick), this refers to the window and not the object.

3) It looks like your ternary expressions are always evaluating to false. You need to rethink them.

P.S. I looked at the straight JS version

Comment: **1**- Why should that matter? What if there is nothing to return? **2**- I have already created references outside event listener. I haven't referenced `this` but I have referenced each of the events I am calling. How is what you proposed different from what I already did?
**3**- Yes that is another question, *why is CoffeeScript doing this?* Turning simple ternary statement into something way more complex that I cannot even understand?

Comment: I am not questioning everything *just because*... I am actually gonna do what you proposed in the answer. The questions I asked are so I understand what I am doing and have a clearer picture next time.

Comment: I did as you said, and it worked!! I think I have an answer for **#2**. When I define `_getTitle` or `_getPurpose` as references to the methods that are the properties of `myObject` they still are the properties of `myObject` but they are executed out of context, in context of `window` (from within the event handler). Defining a reference to `this` inside `myMethod()` and then calling the methods *as properties of* the object, calls them in the proper context. Is that it?

Comment: Sorry for so many comments. I got the definite answer to **#3**. I was doing it wrong. The correct syntax for ternary statements in CoffeeScript is different from plain JavaScript. I changed it to `if typeof title is undefined then "MyClass" else title` and it transcompiles it to: `typeof title === undefined ? "MyClass" : title` which works fine. I still don't have an answer for **#1**.

Comment: @ZiaUrRehman typically if you name something `get___` than you want to return something from it. i.e. in this case, you want to get the title and/or purpose. In your case, if you did `var _title = obj.getTitle()`, it would be undefined, because nothing is being returned from that method.

Comment: Oh, I completely ignored that. Maybe because I wasn't paying attention to the names of methods. Thank you for pointing that out.